# A table of 2 directions (string <-> token) in parsing

Tags: parsing, ocaml, lexer, ocamlyacc, ocamllex

I have defined a hash table `keyword_table` to store all the keywords of my language. Here is part of the code:

```
(* parser.mly *)
%token CALL CASE CLOSE CONST
...  
reserved_identifier:
| CALL { "Call" }
| CASE { "Case" }
| CLOSE { "Close" }
| CONST { "Const" }
...

(* lexer.mll *)
{let hash_table list =
  let tbl = Hashtbl.create (List.length list) in
  List.iter (fun (s, t) -> Hashtbl.add tbl (lowercase s) t) list;
  tbl

let keyword_table = hash_table [
  "Call", CALL; "Case", CASE; "Close", CLOSE; "Const", CONST;
  ... ]}

rule token = parse
  | lex_identifier as li
     { try Hashtbl.find keyword_table (lowercase li)  
       with Not_found -> IDENTIFIER li }
```

As there are a lot of keywords, I really would like to avoid as much as possible from repeat code.

In `parser.mly`, it seems that `%token CALL CASE ...` could not be simplified, because each token must be defined explicitly. However, for `reserved_identifier` part, is there possible to call a function to return a string from a token, instead of hard coding each string?

So, that suggests probably that a hash table is not suitable for this purpose. Which data structure is best choice for a search from both sides (we assume that each key from both sides is unique)? As a result, we want to realize `find_0 table "Call"` returns token `CALL` (used in `lexer.mll`) and `find_1 table CALL` returns `"Call"` (used in `parser.mly`).

Also, if this `table` can be defined, where should I put it so that `parser.mly` can use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to get the string while you are in the lexer, precisely at the point that is matching the token (eg. `Lexing.lexeme`). It is too late to try to get it in the parser. We don't want the token stream to keep all strings in memory as it would increase memory consumption a lot (in practice most tokens never need their string representation).

Why don't you build a reverse table from keyword values (or token values) to string, at the same time you build the first mapping ? `hash_table` could be renamed into `hash_tables` and return the two reverse maps.

It probably needs to be defined in the parser if you want it visible from both the parser and the lexer.